# React native 'this' references dedicatedWorkerGlobalScope instead of class instance

Tags: react-native, google-chrome-devtools

I have a component that I want to capture gesture events for using panResponder, however while trying to debug remotely (within chome) the 'this' context is referencing an instance of DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope instead of the class instance.

Say I have a simple component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
    View,
    Text
    PanResponder
} from 'react-native';


class MyC extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);
      this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({

            onStartShouldSetPanResponder : () => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder : () => true,
            onPanResponderGrant : this.panResponderGranted ,
      })
    }

    panResponderGranted = (e, gestureState) => {

       this.setState({offset : gestureState.dx}); //this.setState is undefined
    }

    render(){

      return (<View />)
    }

}
```

now whenever I step through the panResponderGranted function and I look at the first level closure, I can see that there is a variable named  _this that has the correct reference to the instance of the class. I am debugging wrong? is this expected behavior, or a bug?

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `panResponderGranted`, because ES6 doesn't automatically bind functions.

I.e.

```
onPanResponderGrant : this.panResponderGranted.bind(this),
```

Comment: But look closely at the function expression, I am assigning instead of declaring the function, and being that this is an arrow function my understanding is that that correctly binds its context to the instance.

Comment: Actually, no I just tried it and that solved my problem.. But I find it very weird that it never threw any undefined errors this entire time. The function would execute but the debugger wouldn't pick up the values. I appended `.bind(this)` to the `.create` methods and I can now see the values on the debugger. Also just to defend my first comment, I am basing my code on [react-native-drawer](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/blob/master/index.js#L187) that has the functions assigned to a property, and that properly binds the `this` context....